Can i prove that (p → q) ∨ (p → r) ≡ p → (q ∨ r) without using truth table?
My best result was $\neg p \vee (q \vee r) ≡ (\neg p \vee q) ∨ (\neg p \vee r)$
What can i do next?

"What can I do next"? Nothing: you are done! Simply use associativity and commutativity of $\lor$, and $s\lor s\equiv s$.

Use association and commutation to move parnetheses and terms and remove the duplicate $\neg p$ using Idempotence

Since $p\to q \equiv \neg p\vee q$, we can proceed as follows:
\begin{align*}
(p\to q)\vee(p\to r) & \equiv (\neg p\vee q)\vee(\neg p\vee r) \tag{logical identity}\\
& \equiv ((\neg p\vee q)\vee \neg p)\vee r \tag{associativity}\\
& \equiv (\neg p\vee(q\vee\neg p))\vee r \tag{associativity}\\
& \equiv (\neg p\vee(\neg p\vee q))\vee r \tag{commutativity}\\
& \equiv ((\neg p\vee\neg p)\vee q)\vee r \tag{associativty}\\
& \equiv (\neg p\vee q)\vee r \tag{idempotence}\\
& \equiv \neg p\vee(q\vee r) \tag{associativity}\\
& \equiv p\to(q\vee r) \tag{logical identity}
\end{align*}
Hopefully this helps!
